# Deep transforming Hash into the flat Array of paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to get tips and examples of how can convert different structures like this:

```
h = {
    friend: [:id, :name],
    meta: {
        board: [:id, :name],
        column: [:id, :name, users: [:id, :name]]
    },
    trello: [:id, :name]
}
```

into the array like this:

```
[[:friend, :id],
 [:friend, :name],
 [:meta, :board, :id],
 [:meta, :board, :name],
 [:meta, :column, :id],
 [:meta, :column, :name],
 [:meta, :column, :users, :id],
 [:meta, :column, :users, :name],
 [:trello, :id],
 [:trello, :name]]
```

Each element of this array is a full path.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please clarify or remove the last sentence (with an edit). Notice that I made your hash the value of a variable (`h`). That way users can all refer to the same variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty standard [Tree traversal problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). You could use [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) via recursion:

```
# for Array.wrap; It's needed in pure ruby script, not in Rails
require 'active_support/all'

def deep_flatten(tree, path, result)
  tree.each do |key, value|
    Array.wrap(value).each do |e|
      if e.is_a? Hash
        deep_flatten(e, path + [key], result)
      else
        result << path + [key, e]
      end
    end
  end
end

tree = {
  friend: [:id, :name],
  meta: {
    board: [:id, :name],
    column: [:id, :name, users: [:id, :name]]
  },
  trello: [:id, :name]
}

result = []
deep_flatten(tree, [], result)
result.each do |line|
  puts line.inspect
end
```

It outputs:

```
[:friend, :id]
[:friend, :name]
[:meta, :board, :id]
[:meta, :board, :name]
[:meta, :column, :id]
[:meta, :column, :name]
[:meta, :column, :users, :id]
[:meta, :column, :users, :name]
[:trello, :id]
[:trello, :name]
```

[Array.wrap](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class)

Comment: cool, thanks a lot, amazing solution! I've just removed dependency for  Array.wrap and I got the whole idea.

Comment: @Renat Added some links.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def doit(obj)
  case obj
  when Hash
    obj.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
      case v
      when Symbol
        a << v
      else
        doit(v).each { |aa| a << [k, *aa] }
      end
    end
  else
    obj.each_with_object([]) do |v,a|
      case v
      when Symbol
        a << v
      else
        doit(v).each { |aa| a << aa }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

For the hash `h` given in the question the results are as follows.

```
doit(h)
  #=> [[:friend, :id], [:friend, :name],
  #    [:meta, :board, :id], [:meta, :board, :name], [:meta, :column, :id],
  #    [:meta, :column, :name], [:meta, :column, :users, :id],
  #    [:meta, :column, :users, :name],
  #    [:trello, :id], [:trello, :name]]
```

**Explanation**

The operations performed by recursive methods are always difficult to explain. In my experience the best way is to salt the code with `puts` statements. However, that in itself is not enough because when viewing output it is difficult to keep track of the level of recursion at which particular results are obtained, when the method calls itself and which version of itself to which it returns. The solution to that is to indent and un-indent results, which is what I've done below.

```
INDENT = 4

@col = -INDENT

def indent
  @col += INDENT
end

def undent
  @col -= INDENT
end

def pu(s)
  print " "*@col
  puts s
end
```

```
def doit(obj)
  begin                                                  # rem
    indent                                               # rem
    pu "passed obj = #{obj}"                             # rem   
    case obj
    when Hash
      pu "processing hash..."                            # rem
      obj.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
        pu "k=#{k}, v=#{v}, a=#{a}"
        case v
        when Symbol
          a << v
        else
          doit(v).each { |aa| a << [k, *aa] }
        end
      end
    else
```

```
      pu "processing array..."                           # rem
      obj.each_with_object([]) do |v,a|
        pu "v = #{v}"                                    # rem
        pu "a = #{a}"                                    # rem
        case v
        when Symbol
          pu "v is a symbol"                             # rem
          a << v
        else
          pu "calling doit(v). v is a hash or an array"  # rem
          doit(v).each { |aa| a << aa }
        end
      end
    end.
    tap { |o| pu "returning #{o}" }                      # rem
  ensure                                                 # rem
    undent                                               # rem
  end
end
```

The lines ending with `# rem` (for "remove") are the lines I've added to the method.

```
doit(h)
```

causes the following to be displayed.

```
passed obj = {:friend=>[:id, :name], :meta=>{:board=>[:id, :name],
              :column=>[:id, :name, {:users=>[:id, :name]}]}, :trello=>[:id, :name]}
processing hash...
k=friend, v=[:id, :name], a=[]
    passed obj = [:id, :name]
    processing array...
    v = id
    a = []
    v is a symbol
    v = name
    a = [:id]
    v is a symbol
    returning [:id, :name]
```

```
k=meta, v={:board=>[:id, :name], :column=>[:id, :name, {:users=>[:id, :name]}]},
a=[[:friend, :id], [:friend, :name]]
    passed obj = {:board=>[:id, :name],
                  :column=>[:id, :name, {:users=>[:id, :name]}]}
    processing hash...
    k=board, v=[:id, :name], a=[]
        passed obj = [:id, :name]
        processing array...
        v = id
        a = []
        v is a symbol
        v = name
        a = [:id]
        v is a symbol
       returning [:id, :name]
```

```
    k=column, v=[:id, :name, {:users=>[:id, :name]}],
    a=[[:board, :id], [:board, :name]]
        passed obj = [:id, :name, {:users=>[:id, :name]}]
        processing array...
        v = id
        a = []
        v is a symbol
        v = name
        a = [:id]
        v is a symbol
        v = {:users=>[:id, :name]}
        a = [:id, :name]
        calling doit(v). v is a hash or an array
            passed obj = {:users=>[:id, :name]}
            processing hash...
            k=users, v=[:id, :name], a=[]
                passed obj = [:id, :name]
                processing array...
                v = id
                a = []
                v is a symbol
                v = name
                a = [:id]
                v is a symbol
                returning [:id, :name]
            returning [[:users, :id], [:users, :name]]
        returning [:id, :name, [:users, :id], [:users, :name]]
    returning [[:board, :id], [:board, :name], [:column, :id], [:column, :name],     
               [:column, :users, :id], [:column, :users, :name]]
```

```
k=trello, v=[:id, :name], a=[[:friend, :id], [:friend, :name], [:meta, :board, :id],
 [:meta, :board, :name], [:meta, :column, :id], [:meta, :column, :name],
 [:meta, :column, :users, :id], [:meta, :column, :users, :name]]
    passed obj = [:id, :name]
    processing array...
    v = id
    a = []
    v is a symbol
    v = name
    a = [:id]
    v is a symbol
    returning [:id, :name]
returning [[:friend, :id], [:friend, :name], [:meta, :board, :id],
           [:meta, :board, :name], [:meta, :column, :id], [:meta, :column, :name],
           [:meta, :column, :users, :id], [:meta, :column, :users, :name],
           [:trello, :id], [:trello, :name]]
```

```
 #=> [[:friend, :id], [:friend, :name], [:meta, :board, :id], [:meta, :board, :name],
      [:meta, :column, :id], [:meta, :column, :name], [:meta, :column, :users, :id],
      [:meta, :column, :users, :name], [:trello, :id], [:trello, :name]]
```